# EMailing Issue in Rshiny ::Attaching a Data Frame as pdf/.html from Shinyapps.io

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

```
[![i=iris
library(shiny)
library(mailR)

ui =fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    div(id = "login",
        wellPanel(title = "Mail your report", 
                  textInput("to", label = "To:", placeholder = "To:"),
                  textInput("sub","Subject:"),
                  textInput("msg","Message:"),
                  actionButton("mailButton",label = "Send mail") 
        )
    ),tableOutput(outputId = "fo")
    )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$mailButton,{
    isolate({
      send.mail(from = "*****@gmail.com",
                to = unlist(strsplit(input$to, ";", fixed = TRUE)),
                subject = input$sub,
                body = input$msg,
                smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "****@gmail.com", passwd = "******", ssl = TRUE),
                authenticate = TRUE,
                attach.files = "fo",html = TRUE,
                send = TRUE)
    })
  })

  output$fo <- renderTable({ 
    a<- as.data.frame(iris)
    a$new <- a$Sepal.Length+a$Sepal.Width
    a

  })
}
runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))  ][1]][1]
```

Here as we can see that in server function i have computed a new column a$new and entire data frame is saved back to a object so i need to mail this data frame as pdf/csv/.html any possible Format plz do guide on this

Comment: You should post the code as text so that other users can test the code.

Comment: @JakeConway What do you mean by text. The code is already in that form only

Comment: @Veerendra No issue Sir i have already uploaded the code along with it , and fortunately i got the solution also .so Thank you for Commenting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    i=iris
library(shiny)
library(mailR)

a<- as.data.frame(iris)
write.csv(a,file="test.csv")
ui =fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    div(id = "login",
        wellPanel(title = "Mail your report", 
                  textInput("to", label = "To:", placeholder = "To:"),
                  textInput("sub","Subject:"),
                  textInput("msg","Message:"),
                  actionButton("mailButton",label = "Send mail") 
        )
    ),tableOutput(outputId = "fo")
    )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$mailButton,{
    isolate({
      send.mail(from = "****@gmail.com",
                to = unlist(strsplit(input$to, ";", fixed = TRUE)),
                subject = input$sub,
                body = input$msg,
                smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", port = 465, user.name = "****@gmail.com", passwd = "nbwishes", ssl = TRUE),
                authenticate = TRUE,
                attach.files = "test1.csv",html = TRUE,
                send = TRUE)
    })
  })

  output$fo <- renderTable({ 
    a<- as.data.frame(iris)
    a$new <- a$Sepal.Length+a$Sepal.Width
    write.csv(a,file="test1.csv")

  })
}
runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Comment: This is the Solution ,Totally Working !!!! Just Make sure the directory you are working in !!